# ¿Cómo puedo tomar mas de un dato en una BD? (usando una tupla)

Tags: php, mysql

buen día.

Estoy realizando una página web en php, específicamente estoy usando un método de geolocalización con Mapbox, pero estoy utilizando la siguiente parte de código para obtener datos

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$db_user,$db_pass) or die ("Problemas en la conexion");
    if ($conexion){
        mysqli_select_db($conexion,"test") or die ("Error en la base de datos");
        $query="SELECT Nom_Pandilla,ID,Latitud,Longitud,Coordenadas  FROM pandillas_test;";
        $registros = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die ("Error query".mysqli_error());
        echo "<select name='Coordenadas','Nom_Pandilla'>";
        while ($tupla=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
            echo "<option value=".$tupla['Coordenadas'].">".$tupla['Nom_Pandilla']."</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        echo "Error en la Selección de pandillas";
    }
```

Como podrán ver, me muestra los datos de mi BD de la siguiente manera.
[image: Tupla]

Lo que yo hago en el código anterior es obtener la geolocalización de una banda específica, pero yo no quiero obtener solo las coordenadas, sino que quiero obtener también los otros datos (como ID, nombre, etc..)

Para imprimir los datos uso el siguiente código.

```
echo "hola ";
    echo "{$_POST['Coordenadas']}<br>";//Muestra las coordenadas de la pandilla
    echo "Seleccionaste la pandilla: ";
    echo "{$_POST['Nom_Pandilla']}<br>"; //Muestra la pandilla seleccionada (No funciona)
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error. Ya que no tengo seleccionado ningun "Nom_Pandilla"
[image: Error en la Página]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la estructura de tus tablas?

Comment: ¿Y por qué no envías únicamente el `ID` del registro y ya después recuperas todos los campos que necesites directamente de la base de datos? ¿O piensas enviar esa información a un servidor externo?

Comment: Puedes usar atributos data- para incluir información adicional en los opción o ponerlos en el value con un separador y luego usar Split en el cliente para recuperarlos diferenciados.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asignar dos nombres a un mismo elemento de formulario:

```
    echo "<select name='Coordenadas','Nom_Pandilla'>";
```

Esto solo asigna el nombre "Coordenadas". Aparte, te sugiero encerrar entre comillas los atributos de HTML para evitar errores. Puedes escapar las comillas anteponiendo una diagonal invertida y, para evitar concatenaciones, encerrar entre llaves los elementos de arreglos:

```
    $query = "SELECT Nom_Pandilla, ID, Latitud, Longitud, Coordenadas FROM pandillas_test;";
    $registros = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die ("Error query".mysqli_error());
    echo "<select name=\"Coordenadas\">";
    while($tupla=mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros)) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$tupla['Coordenadas']}\">{$tupla['Nom_Pandilla']}</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Con esto ya tienes un HTML correcto y ahora solo falta ver cómo hacer para obtener ambos datos, ahora solo falta ver cómo obtener los dos datos que necesitas:

**Opción 1:** Usar las coordenadas para obtener el nombre

Lo ideal sería usar ID para asegurar que el resultado es correcto, pero también se puede con coordenadas, suponiendo que se trata de valores únicos.

En PHP recibes solo `$_POST['Coordenadas']` y lo usas para obtener nombre y, de paso, validar que existe:

```
<?php
// Usa asignación ternaria para asegurar que tienes un valor, aunque sea cadena vacía
$coordenadas = (isset($_POST['Coordenadas'])) ? $_POST['Coordenadas'] : '';
// Verificar que no es cadena vacía
if($coordenadas != '') {
    // Es mejor usar sentencias preparadas, esto es solo ejemplo
    $coordenadas = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $coordenadas);
    // Buscar nombre por coordenadas
    $query = "SELECT Nom_Pandilla FROM pandillas_test WHERE Coordenadas = '$coordenadas'";
    // Ejecutar consulta
    $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    // Leer
    if($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conexion, $res)) {
        // Sí se encontró el registro por Coordenadas
        echo 'Nombre: ' . $fila['Nom_Pandilla'];
    } else {
        // No se encontró
        echo 'Error: Pandilla no encontrada.';
    }
}
```

**Opción 2:** Crear un campo oculto y actualizar con Javascript

En PHP creas los campos asignando ID para poder acceder y manipular fácilmente

```
    $query = "SELECT Nom_Pandilla, ID, Latitud, Longitud, Coordenadas FROM pandillas_test;";
    $registros = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die ("Error query".mysqli_error());
    // Asignar ID
    echo "<select name=\"Coordenadas\" id="\Coordenadas\">";
    while($tupla=mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros)) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$tupla['Coordenadas']}\">{$tupla['Nom_Pandilla']}</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    // Crear campo oculto con ID para acceder
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="Nom_Pandilla" id="Nom_Pandilla" value="">';
```

En Javascript escuchas cambios en el select para actualizar el campo oculto:

```
<script>
document.querySelector('#Coordenadas').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // Obtener texto seleccionado
    let nombre = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    // Asignar a campo oculto
    document.querySelector('#Nom_Pandilla').value = nombre;
});
</script>
```

Con esto ya no habrá errores en tu código original:

```
echo "hola ";
echo "{$_POST['Coordenadas']}<br>"; //Muestra las coordenadas de la pandilla
echo "Seleccionaste la pandilla: ";
echo "{$_POST['Nom_Pandilla']}<br>"; //Muestra la pandilla seleccionada (No funciona)
```

Seguramente hay más opciones, pero estas dos son las que me parecen más viables.