# como obtengo el valor del texto de mi SELECT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

quiero obtener el select dependiente, al momento de hacerlo obtengo solo el id, por medio de post aqui es cuando tengo el id y el nombre

```
<?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_marca']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nom_marca']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
```

si cambio id_marca obio me da el nombre del select pero ya no hay relacion con los demas select que tengo, hay una forma de obtener el texto que almacena el de nom_marca

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/456313/54039), parece que se trata de lo mismo.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta pregunta con su respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266251/guardar-texto-de-un-select-en-mysql

Comment: ¿Has intentando algo? ¿Dónde lo quieres recuperar (supongo que en el cliente)? Para los `option` el valor que quieres estaría en la [propiedad `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) si estás usando Javascript.